# i need to return column number from sorting selected row

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

i have a table like this:

```
| uid |    date    |
+-----+------------+ 
| 032 | 16-04-2022 |
| 453 | 15-04-2022 |
| 425 | 13-04-2022 |
| 563 | 14-04-2022 |
```

i need to sorting them and return with new column like this:

```
| uid |    date    | num |
+-----+------------+-----+
| 425 | 13-04-2022 |  1  |
| 563 | 14-04-2022 |  2  |
| 453 | 15-04-2022 |  3  |
| 032 | 16-04-2022 |  4  |
```

Comment: num column is coming from which table ?

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE(UID,DATED)AS
(
  SELECT '032',TO_DATE('16-04-2022','DD-MM-YYYY')UNION ALL
  SELECT '453',TO_DATE('15-04-2022','DD-MM-YYYY')UNION ALL 
  SELECT '425',TO_DATE('13-04-2022','DD-MM-YYYY')UNION ALL
  SELECT '563',TO_DATE('14-04-2022','DD-MM-YYYY') 
)

SELECT C.UID,C.DATED,
  ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY C.DATED ASC)NUM
 FROM CTE AS C
```

You can use ROW_NUMBER()-functionality. CTE is representation of your table's data